# Optimizing the large amount of data SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not so good in optimizing the SQL query and need expert help in it . 
I will be grateful if you help me to optimize the below query so that it can run in more efficiently. 
The execution of this query is taking too much ~1 minute.

```
    select distinct oninf.out_id,ob.report_id,cq.total_out, rep.epi_id ,rep.r_id     
                        from o_infos oninf
                        inner join o_for_events ob on oninf.out_id = ob.out_id 
                        left outer Join cluster_quantities cq on oninf.out_id = cq.out_id 
                        inner join reports rep on ob.epi_id = rep.epi_id                
                        inner join reports_infos rinf on rep.r_id = rinf.r_id
                        inner Join o_sp_quantity osq on osq.out_id  = oninf.out_id 
                        where rinf.r_type in ('SS', 'DM') and rinf.status in('V')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thank you . Is it possible to optimize the joins of this query  ? Its taking too much of time to execute

Comment: Your question requires us to understand whether the time of the query is actually reasonable or not.  As far as we know, it may be blazingly fast for the enormous datasets in the tables being joined.  Could you provide a copy of the query plan (with EXPLAIN ANALYSE) in your question please?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

1) Gather stats, vacuum analysis on tables if required
2) Check AWR report (Automatic work load report) to see if any thing can be improved like I/O operation, CPU usages etc.
3) You might have to look if any thing can be improved from parallel execution front:
https://www.postgresql.eu/events/pgconfeu2018/sessions/session/2140/slides/141/PQ_PGCON_EU_2018.pdf
4) If nothing above works then see what indexes you have created and how you are using them. Make appropriate use of indexing as required.
5) If issue still persists then you can break the logic into intermediate tables, use these intermediate tables in your join caluse. This way you will have to join less number of tables and would be making use of pre calculated results in intermediate tables.

Comment: AWR is an Oracle only feature that is not available for PostreSQL.